# how to use following commands using yum

Tags: php, linux, redhat

I want to execute following commands using yum (redhat linux)

```
apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
apt-get install gnupg libgpg-error-dev libassuan-dev libgpgme11-dev
apt-get install php5-dev php-pear
```

Comment: replace `apt-get` by `yum` ?

Comment: I can not find these packages on yum

Comment: just google how install php in redhat

Comment: your trying to install Debian packages on red hat? openssl-devel might pull in the stuff your looking for, but is not build-essential itself. Also to install php-5-dev -- yum install php-devel

Answer (score 1):

Installing gnupg prerequisite

```
yum install gcc libgpg-error gpgme gpgme-devel
```

after that

```
pecl install gnupg
```

configuration option “php_ini” is not set to php.ini location
You should add “extension=gnupg.so” to php.ini

Now, add the ‘gnupg.so‘ extension to ‘/etc/php.ini‘ file.

```
echo extension=gnupg.so >> /etc/php.ini
service httpd restart
php -m | grep gnupg

gnupg
```

That’s it.